# How to change reactstrap dropdown icon?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks, reactstrap

How to change reactstrap default dropdown icon into my own image icon?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Quo Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

And if possible, please teach me how to use it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Font Awesome` for that.

Here is the project link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-i3dukw?file=index.js